# How to convert regular expression to CFG?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, computation-theory

How can I convert the regular expression `(ab*)*b` to a context-free grammar?

When I look for examples I keep seeing plus signs in the expression but I don’t have any. Is that just a different way of writing it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. I'd recommend asking this over at [Computer Science.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) instead where the focus is on CS theory.

Answer (score 2):

You can recursively apply the following rules, each of which changes a single regular expression operator into a non-terminal. (Use a different non-terminal name for each operator.) In the following, `R` and `S` are translation of the operands of the regular expression operator; `N` is the non-terminal into which this operator is translated. Terminals are simply passed through unchanged.

1. Concatenation:

   ```
   R S ⇒   N → R
   ```
2. Alternation:

   ```
   R | S ⇒ N → R
           N → S
   ```
3. Kleene star:

   ```
   R* ⇒    N → ε
           N → N R
   ```
4. Kleene plus:

   ```
   R+ ⇒    N → R
           N → N R
   ```
5. Optional:

   ```
   R? ⇒    N → ε
           N → R
   ```

For example,

```
Regex               Transform          Productions
(a b* )*b           3. b* ⇒ N1          N1 → ε
                                       N1 → N1 b
( aN1 )*b           1. aN1 ⇒ N2         N2 → a N1
N2* b               3. N2* ⇒ N3         N3 → ε
                                       N3 → N3 N2
N3b                 1. N3b ⇒ N4         N4 → N3 b
```